# How to realize the contribution of each row in the Fourier Transform of an image?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

Let me first show you what I have done so far.

```
img1 = RemoveAlphaChannel[
   ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"]];
data = ImageData[img];
{nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[data];
 d = data;
d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
ft = Fourier[d];
ftAbs = Abs[ft];
ftArg = Arg[ft];
```

This will give me the information about the image in the Fourier domain. Now let's make a copy of this information.

```
tempAbs = ftAbs;
tempArg = ftArg;
```

To look at the contribution for each row in the Fourier domain to the image

```
Manipulate[
 tempAbs[[All, All]] = 0;
 tempArg[[All, All]] = 0;
 tempAbs[[All, n]] = ftAbs[[All, n]];
 tempArg[[All, n]] = ftArg[[All, n]];
 ImageAdjust[Image[Abs[InverseFourier[(tempAbs E^(I tempArg))]]]],
 {n, 1, nCol, 1}
]
```

And to check the cumulative contribution

```
Manipulate[
 tempAbs[[All, All]] = 0;
 tempArg[[All, All]] = 0;
 Table[{tempAbs[[All, i]] = ftAbs[[All, i]];
 tempArg[[All, i]] = ftArg[[All, i]];}, {i, 1, n}];
 ImageAdjust[Image[Abs[InverseFourier[(tempAbs E^(I tempArg))]]]],
 {n, 1, nCol, 1}
]
```

If I take the individual contributions for the first `m` rows (say, `5`), I will get `5` different images (say, `I1`,`I2`,`I3`,`I4`and`I5`). And if I take the cumulative contribution up to the fifth row, I will get another image (say, `I15`).

My question is what is the relation between  `I15` and `I1`,`I2`,`I3`,`I4`and`I5`? To be more precise, how can I combine these five images to get `I15`?

Comment: You probably want `Re[InverseFourier[...` instead of `Abs[InverseFourier[...`. Then `I15` should be the sum of `I1`..`I5`. Fourier transform is linear, so `Fourier[I1]+Fourier[I2]+Fourier[I3] = Fourier[I1+I2+I3]`

Comment: @nikie I want to use `Abs` instead of `Re`. I know Fourier Transform is linear but I am not sure whether they contribute linearly or not. Are you saying that the relation should be `I15=I1+I2+I3+I4+I5`?

Comment: Not if you use `Abs`. `Abs[Exp[I*x]+Exp[I*y]] != Abs[Exp[I*x]]+Abs[Exp[I*y]]`

Comment: @nikie Then what would be the relationship between the images?

Comment: It's not noise, so there is a relationship, but it's not invertible and I don't see how you can gain any insight from it. Look at it this way: If you take a 1d Fourier transform, and delete every frequency except one, take the inverse Fourier transform, then you get the time domain of that frequency. If you take the *absolute* in the time domain, you get a *constant* signal. If you delete all but two frequencies, you get some interference, but you still can't say much about the original signal.

Comment: Or, to put it another way: What's the relationship between `Abs[x+y+z]` and `Abs[x]+Abs[y]+Abs[z]`? Especially if `x`, `y`, `z` are all complex numbers. I'm not sure there is any useful relationship.

Comment: @nikie `Abs[x+y+z]^2=(Re[x]+Re[y]+Re[z])^2+(Im[x]+Im[y]+Im[z])^2` and `Abs[x]^2+Abs[y]^2+Abs[z]^2=Re[x]^2+Re[y]^2+Re[z]^2+Im[x]^2+Im[y]^2+Im[z]^2`.